# Texture paint not following UV Map?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

For some odd reason when I paint on my model the texture paint refuses to follow the UV Map I created. When I painted on the models head the neck was painted on the model. When I tried to find the arms I found that one tiny point on the texture image colors the entire arm and hands?
[image: Screenshot of texture paint]

Ive checked the normals and they are fine and I even tried Smart UV unwrap and even tried applying my mirror modifier and yet nothing changes.

Comment: hello maybe you've created a new UV map? (in the Object Data panel > UV Maps)

Comment: please share your file so that we can check

Comment: @moonboots That was it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You've created a new UV map in the *Object Data* panel > *UV Maps*, remove it.